# Is it defined behavior to allocate memory using the variable being declared?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, sizeof, undefined-behavior

I was looking at a port of libusb today for android and I noticed this line of code:

```
struct usbi_pollfd *ipollfd = malloc(sizeof(*ipollfd));
```

It seems that `ipollfd` is being allocated based on the size of itself which has not been completely allocated yet. My first thought would be that the behavior of this is undefined. Is that the case?

Answer (score 7):

It's **fine and well-defined behaviour**.

`sizeof` gets evaluated at compile-time, and unless the operand is VLA, the *operand* is not evaluated. (*So, no invalid-pointer dererefence, as it might look like*)

To put it in other words, `sizeof` only needs to know the *type* of the operand (which is already defined).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4

> [....] If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.